# I have an error in Android studio, Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

Why build.gradle is not going to plugin with 'com.google.gms.google-services'?

How to add google-services.json file in our app? And How add the successful connection of that file into our gradle file?

Comment: are you running on mac or windows?

Comment: are you working on push notification?@PankajLagad

Comment: @PankajLagad check my answer

Comment: @Rushabh042 Hi Do you have working code of Push notification?

Comment: @Rushabh042 mail me that code at, lagadpankaj@gmail.com

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start